# margin-top in percentage not working as expected

Tags: html, css, margin

I know what you're thinking, but the parent container(s) are all positioned with pixels.

I have a div with a height and width in pixels, inside that div I have a youtube iframe that has (for this example) it's `margin-top` in percentage.

This the HTML:

[image: Elements console]

And this is the result:

[image]

I know it's a ridiculously small frame (right bottom of selected div) but it's just an example :)

As you can see, in code I have the `margin-top` set to `99%` but it's actually positioned a lot lower. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Could you put together a jsfiddle or plunkr that demonstrates the issue you are having? Please use the minimum amount of code to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The point is that a percentage value for top/bottom [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)/[`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) properties is relative to the **width** of the box's containing block. It doesn't respect the height of the parent element.

> **[8.3 Margin properties: 'margin-top', 'margin-right', 'margin-bottom', 'margin-left', and 'margin'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties)**
>
> `<percentage>` The percentage is calculated with respect to the width
>   of the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for
>   `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` as well. If the containing block's
>   width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined
>   in CSS 2.1.

As you are using `absolute` positioning, try using [`top: 99%`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-top) instead in which a *percentage* value refers to the **height** of the box's containing block.

Comment: Whow, there's a big black whole in my css knowledge... I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: Is there an alternative for paddings in percentage with absolute positioning too?

Comment: @RobbieVercammen IMO you could position the child element relatively and use percentage values for its `top` property instead of using padding in percentage for the parent.

Comment: I actually need the padding for a hyperlink without text. Otherwise, I couldn't define the height or width when I use display: inline-block.

Comment: It would be better if you could provide a minimal example at jsfiddle. Also please consider posting this issue as a separate question if it's needed, as it's a quiet different than the current one.

Answer (score 4):

A percentage based margin-top value won't work because it is calculated from the width of the containing element, as previously stated.

If you need a fluid, responsive, scalable margin based on width and can't use absolute positioning try using viewport units in your CSS. Viewport units behave very similarly to percentage based dimensions except that they are calculated from the dimensions of your viewport window and will scale and resize according to the dimensions of your browser window.

**vw** = Viewport Width: This measurement is based on the width of the viewport. A value of 1vw equals 1% of the viewport width.

**vh** = Viewport Height: This measurement is based on the height of the viewport. A value of 1vh equals 1% of the viewport height.

You can use decimals of percentages also, like so-

```
.container {
    margin-top: .3vw;
}
```

Viewport units were not that widely supported a few years ago, but all modern browsers support them now. If you familiarize yourself with them it will open up a lot more options for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to position an element set to `position: absolute`, you can use `top:`, `bottom:`, `right:` `left:` to place it where you want. E.g.

```
element {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```